# Pattern Matching On Java Syntax (Checkstyle)

Tags: java, syntax, pattern-matching, checkstyle

I am currently trying to create my own check in Checkstyle.
It's supposed to throw a warning for commented Code inside a class.

Now, as far as the recognition of comments goes, I got it all figured out, but now I'm facing the problem of how to make it recognize Java Code.

Are there any collections which provide these features already? Just checking for certain keywords like modifiers, types, scopes, etc. would be too vague in some situations.

tl;dr: Looking for a way to find out if a string is java code or not (pattern matching)

Answer (score 0):

It would be very hard to determine if a line is Java code or not, as a line can be as little as a single `}`. That said, if you want to check if a FILE is java, there are some good Regex options for you, mostly because you can look at the context of a certain line.
Even if you use those you could craft a specific file that will be detected as if it were Java, while it actually isn't. That said, it would work for most if not all "normal" files.

If the Regex is what you're looking for, you might want to look for similar threats on StackOverflow, because there should be a few around (I used one myself a while ago). If you really want to do this in Checkstyle however, you might be out of luck...

Answer (score 0):

A good heuristic method to determine large blocks of commented code is to check for preceding spaces. A "valid" comment will usually be indented with the actual code:

```
public class A {

   public void a() {
       // valid comment
       ...
   }

}
```

Whereas a code block that has been commented with ctrl-7 will directly start with the // characters:

```
public class A {

//   public void a() {
//       // valid comment
//       ...
//   }

}
```

Thus, your regular expression would look something like this

```
^//.*
```